# Get actual address of variable in memory

Tags: c++, memory

I use array like this multiset::iterator it[100]
When I do this: it[0] = mymultiset.insert(15) and then it[1] = mymultiset.insert(17) I get the same address like 00C0E960 (with %p) or 12642656 (with %d).
My problem is, i need actual address not this ... for comparing with another iterator.

pseudocode:

```
multiset<int> a;
multiset<int>::iterator x1, x2;
multiset<int>::iterator it[10000];
int j = 0
it[j] = a.insert(15);
x1 = x2 = it[j];
j++;
it[j] = a.insert(74);
x1 = it[j];
printf("Value: %d, addressP: %p, addressD: %d\n", *it[0], it[0], it[0]);
printf("Value: %d, addressP: %p, addressD: %d\n", *x1, x1, x1);
printf("Value: %d, addressP: %p, addressD: %d\n", *it[1], it[1], it[1]);
printf("Value: %d, addressP: %p, addressD: %d\n", *x2, x2, x2);
```

output:

```
Value: 15, addressP: 00BDF0F0, addressD: 12447984
Value: 15, addressP: 00BDF0F0, addressD: 12447984
Value: 74, addressP: 00BDF0F0, addressD: 12447984
Value: 74, addressP: 00BDF0F0, addressD: 12447984
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you should obtain the address of the iterator objects with `&` when trying to print their addresses. I'm not sure what printing an iterator as an address would do, I suspect it isn't defined.

Comment: Kind of sounds like an XY problem.  What problem are you trying solve with this?

Comment: Your `printf` calls have three conversion specifiers, yet only two arguments. The `%p` conversion specifier requires an argument of type `void *`; the variable argument function call mechanism used by `printf` does nothing to ensure that an argument is converted to this type.

Comment: *Turn your compiler warnings on.*  The compiler will tell you at least two different things that are wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `printf()` has three format specifiers and only two arguments for them, so the third value printed is undefined.

To see the address of the value you would need both a `*` to dereference and then a `&` to get the address.

Here's an example of it fixed:

```
printf("Value: %d, iterator pointer addr: %p, value address: %d\n", *x1, x1, &(*x1));
```

Comment: I edit my post to correct it (its  not  copy of my code (just values of outputs), therefore that mistake), but realy thx, &(*x1) return differend number for each insert, so its looks, that can help

Comment: Someone downvoted this. Is there a problem with the answer? Please let me know if so

Comment: I think, system of vote on this site is realy crazy, whoever just downvote good anwer without at least comment with clearify, why he do that. I created this question, so if the answer helped me with solve my problem, I think its good answer. Whoever used this answer and it not solve their problem, first should realy good read the question, if contained what they need...